# how Connect JS mqtt sub and pub to AWS EC2 whit ssh?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, mqtt, mosca

I am making an IOT application and i am using mosca as the broker (node.js on AWS EC2). I can`t connect and subscribe or publish, I don't now what is bad or what i am missing.the Broker works and when i run SUB and PUB nothing happen,don't show me erros, just nothin , but a do't see the message

// Mosca Mqtt broker

```
var mosca = require('mosca')
var settings = {port: 1883} //pueto del servidor normalmente 1883
var broker = new mosca.Server(settings)

broker.on('ready', ()=>{// se le dice al servido que se prenda 
    console.log('broker is ready to use')
})
broker.on('clientConnected',()=>{

    console.log('some one is connect')    
})

broker.on('published',(packet)=>{
     console.log(packet.payload.toString())

})
```

// SUB

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
const fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var client = mqtt.connect('mqtts://ec2-44-230-22-151.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com',{
port: 1883,
key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'/servidorIOT2.pem')),
cliendID: 'ubuntu',

}
);

// ip del servidor 
var topic = 'prueba1'// topico al que me susbri

client.on('connect',()=>{
    client.subscribe(topic)
})

client.on('message', (topic,mensaje)=>{
mensaje1 = mensaje.toString()
console.log(mensaje1)

})
```

// mqtt PUB

```
var path = require('path');
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var fs = require('fs')
var client = mqtt.connect('mqtts://ec2-44-230-22-151.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com',{
port: 1883,
key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'/servidorIOT2.pem')),
cliendID: 'ubuntu',

}
);

var topic = 'prueba1'
var mensaje = 'Hello , i am here'// mensaje que se va a mandar 

client.on('connect',()=>{
setInterval(()=>{
    client.publish(topic,mensaje)
    console.log('already send:',mensaje)
},5000)

})
console.log('llego hasta aqui')
```

any idea? , Tanks
[:(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKBZX.png)

Comment: Please do not post images of code, they are hard to read and impossible for people that use screen readers. Post the code it's self and use the tool bar to format it.

Comment: Why are you using `mqtts://` when your broker doesn't support MQTT over TLS?

Comment: You appear to have removed the code for your broker. Add that back in so we can see how it's configured. (But as I said in my previous comment it looks like you haven't set up any SSL/TLS)